# how can i change build.serial on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an Android application that I am testing on an emulator (SDK emulator running Nougat). I would like to get the Serial Number of the Device.

In the emulator, I see the below build.Serial value.

Do I have a chance to change it? Can we do something like this for the emulator?

`Build.SERIAL = unknown`

Answer (score 0):

Build.SERIAL is deprecated for apps that target Android O or newer, I know that you are trying on Nougat but maybe your targetSdkVersion is > Oreo, for that you are getting "UNKNOW". You need to use Build.getSerial(), which require some runtime permissions.

For more information Device Identifiers check the official documentation:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html